# Can't get localhost database in Codeigniter to render data

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have Codeigniter setup on localhost.  I'm not getting any database connection errors, but when I try to do a simple dump of the test data I have in my table, nothing gets displayed.

I setup autoload as follows:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

I setup the database config as follows:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'ci_series';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

here is my model:

```
class Post extends CI_Model{
    public function get_posts($num=20,$start=0){
        $this->db->select()->from('posts')->where('active',1)->order_by('date_added','desc')->limit(0,20);
        $query=$this->db->get();
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

Here is my controller:

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller{
    public function index(){
        $this->load->model('post');
        $data['posts']=$this->post->get_posts();
        echo "<pre>";print_r($data['posts']);echo"</pre>";
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: There must be something else: `$data['posts']`, at the minimum, is an empty array

Comment: In your `->limit(0,20)` call, the first parameter is the limit, the second is your offset. So you are limiting your rows to 0?